# FaceBook SDK app permission miss behavior (Permission List empty if app not installed)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Here is my full source code for sharing app in Facebook,

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
        .asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                     Exception exception)
    {
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization
                && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED))
        {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            shareThisLevelOnFacebook();
        }
        else if (session.isOpened())
        {
            shareThisLevelOnFacebook();
        }
    }
};


private boolean isLoggedInFacebook()
{
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void shareThisLevelOnFacebook()
{
    if(curWeatherBitmap == null) return;

    boolean isLoggedIn = isLoggedInFacebook();
    if (!isLoggedIn)
    {
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    }
    else
    {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = Session.getActiveSession()
                .getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
        {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS);
            Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(
                    newPermissionsRequest);

            return;
        }


        Request reqPost = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), curWeatherBitmap, null);

        //Parameters-info can be found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
        Bundle postParams = reqPost.getParameters();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(" Default image title");

        postParams.putString("name", sb.toString());

        reqPost.setParameters(postParams);
        reqPost.setCallback(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(WeatherDetailActivity.this,
                            "Posted on Facebook has been finished",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(WeatherDetailActivity.this,
                            "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                            error.getErrorMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        reqPost.executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Which works fine, when device have facebook app installed. But if not,

```
List<String> permissions = Session.getActiveSession()
                .getPermissions();
```

Always return an empty permission list, So it creates kind of loop (permission request, permission list empty, again request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an explicit refresh of permissions.

```
Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
s.refreshPermissions();
```

That will cause your permissions to be refreshed from the server and updated in the status callback.  That should be the definitive source of granted permissions.